# Error "too many connections" in Node and MYSQL

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have a script in Node that makes about 4 or 5 requests to MYSQL, but it seems that there is some overload, because after inserting 4 or 5 records I get: "Too many connections"

Below I leave my code

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
var fs = require('fs');
const mysql = require('mysql2');

const mysqlConOptions = {
    connectionLimit : 10, // default = 10
  host: "127.0.0.1",
  user: "root",
  password: "root123!",
  database: "scraperpeli"
};
var con = mysql.createPool(mysqlConOptions);

con.getConnection(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Conectado!");
});

function insertarpost()

{
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  var sql = "INSERT INTO `wp_posts` ( `post_author`, `post_date`, `post_date_gmt`, `post_content`, `post_title`,`post_excerpt`, `post_status`,`comment_status`, `ping_status`,`post_password`, `post_name`,`to_ping`,`pinged`, `post_modified`, `post_modified_gmt`,`post_content_filtered`,`post_parent`, `guid`,`menu_order`, `post_type`, `post_mime_type`,`comment_count`) VALUES (1, '"+fhoy+"', '"+fhoy+"', '"+description+"', '"+title+"','', 'publish', 'open', 'closed','','"+slug+"','','', '"+fhoy+"', '"+fhoy+"','', '0','','0', 'movies','' ,0);";
  con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    if (err)  throw err;
    resolve(result);
    console.log("1 registro insertado");
  });

});
}

insertarpost().then(obtenerultimopostid);
function obtenerultimopostid() {
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  con.query("SELECT ID FROM wp_posts ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 0,1;", function (err, result, fields) {
  console.log(result);
    var sql = "INSERT INTO wp_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES ("+result[0].ID+",'runtime', '"+runtime+"'),("+result[0].ID+",'original_title','"+titleoriginal+"'),("+result[0].ID+",'Rated','"+cpgrated+"'),("+result[0].ID+",'Country', '"+country+"'),("+result[0].ID+",'date', '"+datemovie+"'),("+result[0].ID+",'imdbRating', '"+repimdb+"'),("+result[0].ID+",'vote_average', '"+reptmdb+"'),("+result[0].ID+",'imdbVotes', '"+quantimdb+"'),("+result[0].ID+",'vote_count', '"+quanttmdb+"'),("+result[0].ID+",'tagline', '"+tagline+"'),("+result[0].ID+",'dt_poster', '"+poster+"'),("+result[0].ID+",'dt_backdrop', '"+backdrop+"'),("+result[0].ID+",'imagenes', '"+backdrops+"'),("+result[0].ID+",'dt_cast', '"+textimgreparto+"'),("+result[0].ID+",'dt_dir', '"+textimgreparto2+"');";
  con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    resolve(result);
    console.log("1 registro wpmeta insertado");
  });

});
  }).then(function() {
let c1='';
con.query("SELECT ID FROM wp_posts ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 0,1;", function(err, result, fields) {
  console.log(result);
  for (var i = 0; i < getData.length; i++) {
    let source = getData[i]["source"];
    let text = getData[i]["text"];
    let quality = getData[i]["quality"];
    let lang = getData[i]["language"];
    new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      let sql = "INSERT INTO `wp_posts` ( `post_author`, `post_date`, `post_date_gmt`, `post_content`, `post_title`,`post_excerpt`, `post_status`,`comment_status`, `ping_status`,`post_password`, `post_name`,`to_ping`,`pinged`, `post_modified`, `post_modified_gmt`,`post_content_filtered`,`post_parent`, `guid`,`menu_order`, `post_type`, `post_mime_type`,`comment_count`) VALUES (1, '" + fhoy + "', '" + fhoy + "', '', '" + make + "','', 'publish', 'closed', 'closed','','" + make + "','','', '" + fhoy + "', '" + fhoy + "','', '" + result[0].ID + "','','0', 'dt_links','' ,0);";
      con.query(sql, function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        c1=result.insertId
        resolve(result);
        console.log("1 registro link insertado");
      });
    }).then(function() {
        console.log(c1);
        let sql = "INSERT INTO wp_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (" + c1 + ",'_dool_url', '" + source + "'),(" + c1 + ",'_dool_type','" + text + "'),(" + c1 + ",'_dool_quality','" + quality + "'),(" + c1 + ",'_dool_lang','" + lang + "');";

        con.query(sql, function(err, result) {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log("1 registro link meta insertado");
        });
        // });

    });
  }
});

}
```

I don't know why that error comes out, too many queries, am I doing something wrong?  thanks.

I have tried increasing the connection limit but nothing, I hope you can guide me to the resolution of the problem

Comment: You might wanna close the connection after the script ends, you have a lot of queries inside a for loop

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: honestly you don't really need to worry about closing connections as much as the 2 queries inside the for loop.... you need to refactor your code